# QGraphicsView RubberBandDrag leaves artifacts

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, artifacts

I have a QGraphicsView and a QGraphicsScene set up without any properties changed but

```
view->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
view->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
```

When dragging arround for a bit the RubberBandDrag leaves artifacts and the RubberBand itself is often rendered incorrectly, missing the sides:

[image: QGraphicsScene RubberBandDrag Artifacts]

Also other graphics items such as a regular QGraphicsRectItem leave these traces. I tried without the antialias but that seems to make it even worse.

Do I have to set specific properties of the view/scene such as disabling optimization flags?

Or is this just a bug of Qt? (I am using 5.9.2)
At least I couldn't find a report of this.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem. After I play around these two calls, things got fixed.

```
QGraphicsView.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);

QGraphicsView.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
```

Comment: setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate); fixed that for me. Thanks!